# AngularJS ng-pattern weird behavior (regex)

Tags: regex, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I use ng-pattern to validate my client side if a few cases, like looking at password complexity.

Now, I get really strange matches in my regex using ng-pattern. Look at examples down below

```
<span class="registration-error" ng-show="regForm.password.$error.pattern">- Fail to match..</span>
<input type="password" ng-model="registerForm.password" name="password" ng-pattern="/^.*(?=.{8,})(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[\d\W]).*$/"  required/>
```

The above should require 8 characters, at least 1 uppercase character and 1 digit or special character.
For some reason I get a match on words like **FaiLoudD** which doesn't make sense.

I run the same regex in my python backend and it works like a charm.
I also verified the regex using http://regexpal.com/  and it also works perfect.

Why does ng-pattern match so weird?

## Update:

I digged through all modules and the whole building process of my application. The ng-pattern directive started working again when I disabled grunt-html2js in my building process. It seems to have caused ng-pattern to interpret the regex incorrectly. As issue is created at the html2js project. And with that I will close this question.

Comment: This probably won't fix it, but you should remove the `.*` from the beginning of the pattern, because you actually want to have all lookaheads start from the beginning of the string (this should also significantly improve performance).

Comment: Thank m.buettner, did not fix the actual problem but I changed my regex pattern according to your recommendation. Works perfect everywhere except in my client. Ng-pattern still acts really wierd.

Comment: Looks fine on http://plnkr.co/edit/1dYysdjfyYilAP7C5DZy?p=preview .

Comment: Hmm that is really wierd. Yes it works. If I take your code and paste it into my template I get the exact same error. What could possibly disturb ng-pattern to match wrong? I tried to remove all injects and empty my controller to make sure nothing in there did anything but it didnt matter. Same error.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I digged through all modules and the whole building process of my application. The ng-pattern directive started working again when I disabled grunt-html2js in my building process. It seems to have caused ng-pattern to interpret the regex incorrectly. As issue is created at the html2js project. And with that I will close this question.

Both version 0.1.3 and 0.1.6 of grunt-html2js were tested.

## Update

The issue created at the html2js project resulted in version 0.1.7 that resolved the bug.
Thank you karlgoldstein for a quick response and fix.

Comment: It will look a lot more closed if you accept your own answer! :)